# Lambda reading file on S3 - flushing S3 cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a problem regarding cache on S3. Basically I have a lambda that reads a file on S3 which is used as configuration. This file is a JSON. I am using python with boto3 to extract the needed info.

Snippet of my code:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucketname = "configurationbucket"
itemname = "conf.json"
obj = s3.Object(bucketname, itemname)
body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
json_parameters = json.loads(body)  


def my_handler(event, context):
    # using json_paramters data
```

The problem is that when I change the json content and I upload the file again on S3, my lambda seems to read the old values, which I suppose is due to S3 doing caching somewhere.

Now I think that there are two ways to solve this problem:

- to force S3 to invalidate its cache content
- to force my lambda to reload the file from S3 without using the cache

I do prefer the first solution, because I think it will reduce computation time (reloading the file is an expensive procedure). So, how can I flush my cache? I didn't find on console or on AWS guide the way to do this in a simple manner

Comment: Neither S3 nor Lambda have any built in caches.  How are you updating the file?

Comment: Good chance that it is *you* doing caching in your Lambda function. Is the snippet of code that you have shown running inside your Lambda function's event handler or outside of it? Can you expand on your code example?

Comment: @stdunbar by S3 console

Comment: @jarmod it is outside my def handler. I use that configuration file as global

Comment: @jarmod I updated my snippet

Comment: Anything global is going to persist across warm Lambda starts.

Comment: @jarmod is there a way to force lambda to a cold start?

Comment: Update the code or the function configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem is , the code outside of function handler is initialized only once. It won't be re-initialised when the lambda is warm

```
def my_handler(event, context):
    # read from S3 here
    obj = s3.Object(bucketname, itemname)
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    json_parameters = json.loads(body)
    # use json_paramters data
```

Comment: Yes. I found this "problem" now reading this:
https://medium.com/tensult/aws-lambda-function-issues-with-global-variables-eb5785d4b876

Comment: Aws says it's a feature to improve load time